# replace Multiple patterns within a list_file with One in target_file with awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed, gawk

I’m facing a problem

1) I got a list_file intended to be used for inlace replacement like this

```
Replacement pattern ; Matching patterns

EXTRACT ___________________
toto ; tutu | tata | tonton  | titi 
bobo ; bibi | baba | bubu | bebe 
etc. 14000 lines !!!
_____________________________
```

2) I got a target file in witch I want to replace thoses paterns

```
EXTRACT INPUT _______________
hello my name is bob and I am a Titi and I like bubu
_____________________________
```

I want it to become

```
EXTRACT OUTPUT ______________
hello my name is bob and I am a toto and I like bobo
_____________________________
```

for example with one replacement :

```
echo 'toto; tutu | tata | tonton | titi ' | awk '{gsub(/ tutu | tata | tonton | titi /," toto ")}1'
gives
toto; toto | toto | toto | toto
```

with

```
awk -F';' 'NR==FNR{A[$1]=$2; next} IGNORECASE = 1 {for(i in A) gsub(/A[i]/,i)}1’
```

I expect to :

1. register an array A with $2 as content and $1 as key
   so in the fist line
   $2 =' tutu | tata | tonton | titi '
   $1 = ' toto '
2. replace with gsub(/$2/,$1)}1
   so in the fist line
   awk 'IGNORECASE = 1 {gsub(/ tutu | tata | tonton | titi /," toto ")}1

Sadly awk doesn’t seems to understand the pipe « | » character as a OR indicator … I have also tried to achieve this with sed but this option goes very slowly aven if it works :(

does anyone have a better idea ?
Thanks
M

Comment: you need to show the code that isn't working. ***Where*** are you trying to use `|` as on OR operator? When I do `echo a b c | awk '/d|b/'`, I get `a b c` as output. Maybe you can boil your Q down to a test like this? I'm not sure why someone downvoted this. IMHO, a better than average first Q for `awk`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

By putting the array reference inside regexp delimiters you're turning `A[i]` into literal characters in the regexp instead of an array that contains a regexp indexed by a string. Just don't do that. Also your placement of setting IGNORECASE makes no sense. Try this:

```
awk -F';' 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE = 1} NR==FNR{A[$1]=$2; next} {for(i in A) gsub(A[i],i)}1'
```

I'm not saying it's a good idea but it might give you the output you're looking for. Stop using the word "pattern" btw as patterns are for quilts and sweaters - in text matching and replacing use either `regexp` or `string`, whichever one you mean in every context. You'll find it much easier to write and understand code if you understand where regexps vs strings occur.